# Installing BLAS on a mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, lapack, blas

I'm trying to Install BLAS on my Mac, but every time I run make I get this error (shown below the link). I was trying to follow the instructions on [this website](https://pheiter.wordpress.com/2012/09/04/howto-installing-lapack-and-blas-on-mac-os/):

```
gfortran -O3 -c isamax.f -o isamax.o
make: gfortran: No such file or directory
make: *** [isamax.o] Error 1
```

I have no idea what this means or how to fix it so any help would be appreciated. Also I'm trying to install CBLAS and LAPACK so any tips/instructions for that would be nice if you know of a good source...Everything I've found so far is pretty confusing. Also I tried to install ATLAS but it kept not working.

Comment: BLAS, LAPACK, and CBLAS are built into OS X as part of the Accelerate.framework.  There's no need to install them unless you need the most recent version of LAPACK, or have some other specialized requirement.  What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to download Source Exchange and it said i was missing CBLAS and LAPACK

Comment: I've installed BLAS now but installing LAPACK seems really...complicated with all the make.inc files.

Comment: It said you were missing CBLAS and LAPACK when you tried to download it?  I assume you mean when you tried to build it?  Most likely you simply need to configure it to link against Accelerate (-framework Accelerate).

Comment: yeah it said that. I just dowloaded LAPACK actually, but how would the Accelerate command work? I've seen some descriptions of it online but they all seem to say that LAPACK/CBLAS are only on mavericks OSX

Comment: LAPACK and CBLAS have been part of Accelerate for over a decade (since 10.2, IIRC).

Comment: Exactly where is this Accelerate framework? Mine only has a binary vecLib in it.

Comment: accelerate has been around a while but they have not updated the library since lapack 3.2? 3.4??  latest is 3.6.1.  check it out some of those early routines have bugs.

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused because `gfortran` is apparently not installed, so you'll need to download an installer package for `OS X Yosemite 10.10` and install it:

[gfortran 5.1](http://coudert.name/software/gfortran-5.1-Yosemite.dmg) or 
[gfortran 4.9.2](http://coudert.name/software/gfortran-4.9.2-Yosemite.dmg) ([info](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries))

Once installed run the `make` command in the `BLAS` directory.

Answer (score 1):

How to install Blas/Lapack: don't.

These libraries are the textbook example of enormous performance differences between simple and optimized code. And by optimizations I don't mean compiler: I mean algorithm transformations.

So you definitely do not want to download the "reference blas/lapack" from netlib or another location. If your system doesn't already come with an optimized version (Mac OS X does), see if you can get Intel's MKL library (free for students on Linux?), and otherwise get BLIS or OpenBlas or Atlas which are all open source optimized implementations.